# filter_var with array not working correctly

Tags: php

I'm having troubles with filter_var when I try to use it with an array.

Why does this

```
$var = array("http://getbootstrap.com/css/","http://getbootstrap.com/css/");
var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

returns

```
bool(false)
```

?

While this is returning `string(28) "http://getbootstrap.com/css/"` (that means it's a valid URL):

```
$var = "http://getbootstrap.com/css/";
var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

Comment: Why do you think you can send first param as an array? Did you read the documentation. You'd better loop through your array and pass the $value as first param

Comment: Oh, I read the german doc. And there they say you can use an array. Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [filter_var_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php), try

```
$var = array("http://getbootstrap.com/css/","http://getbootstrap.com/css/");
var_dump(filter_var_array($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

Answer (score 1):

All is fine, because `filter_var()` filters only one value at a time. You passed `array()` which is then casted to string, which results in `Array`. And this is not valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

To apply filter for all elements in an array, you should use [`filter_var_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `filter_var` on an array. You have to do this:

```
$result = true;
foreach($var as $elem) {
     $result = $result && filter_var($elem, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
}
```

Another solution is to use [`filter_var_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php).

Comment: The logic was here... I hate using the foreach loop in PHP, the syntax is so weird :-)

Comment: Hehehe, sometimes the arrays are associative, then you need the foreach :)