# Numbering automatically from file name

Tags: php

I have a list of files in a directory and we want them to be numbered like this:

1. file1
2. file2
3. file3

Each file is already numbered, we just need to "extract" the number from the file name. How can I do it in PHP?

Thanks a lot

Comment: glob() to get a file list, then a regular expression. give it a try and ask again if you have some code trouble

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to solve your problem. This might work:

```
$path = '/Library/Of/MyPC/path/to/files/';
$numbers = filter_var_array(array_values(glob($path . "*")), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
var_dump($numbers);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

If it did not work, you may look into these or similar links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366928/how-to-return-just-file-name-using-glob-in-php), [2](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-glob-find-files/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045628/filter-var-with-array-not-working-correctly), [4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506491/php-glob-pattern-match-for-arbitray-number-of-digits), which might help you.